# How to get the cookie value using curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

[image]

Is it possible to get the `crumb` value using curl in php? the `crumb` serves as the cookie in the website

Answer (score 1):

Just ask curl.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://yourhost.com/image.png');
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_info($ch, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
```

$info contains now an array with all known cookies.

As you did not provide enough info, I can only present an example.